# Custom accordion function - undefined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create a reusable accordion function that takes 3 parameters:

1. the element you click
2. the element that gets an `active` class,
3. the element that slides up and down.

Parameter **#1** will change depending on screen size. I'm getting an `undefined` log out on parameter **#3** at the moment.

**http://jsfiddle.net/N2QeD/**

```
var touchClick = "click",
    touchDown = "mousedown",
    rankingObject,
    isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
    touchClick = "touchend";
    touchDown = "touchstart";
}
if (window.navigator.pointerEnabled) {
    touchClick = "pointerup";
    touchDown = "pointerdown";
}

    function accordian(clickMe, addActive, animateMe) {

       clickMe = $(clickMe).attr('class');
       addActive = $(addActive).attr('class');
       animateMe = $(addActive).find(animateMe).attr('class');
       console.log(clickMe);
       console.log(addActive);
       console.log(animateMe);

       clickMe.on(touchClick, function () {
          if (addActive.hasClass('active')) {
              addActive.find(animateMe).slideUp('fast');
              addActive.removeClass('active');;
              return false;
          }
          addActive.each(function () {
              addActive.removeClass('active');
              addActive.find(animateMe).slideDown('fast');
          });
          addActive.find(animateMe).slideDown('fast');
          addActive.addClass('active');
       });
    }
    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
       if ($(window).width() < 769) {
          $('.small_button').on(touchClick, function () {
              var clicked = $(this);
              var active = $('.wrap');
              var animate = $('.wrap .info');
              accordian(clicked, active, animate);
           });
       } else {
           $('.large_button').on(touchClick, function () {
               var clicked = $(this);
               var active = $('.wrap');
               var animate = $('.wrap .info');
               accordian(clicked, active, animate);
           });
       }
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: What is this perversion? `animateMe = $(addActive).find(animateMe).attr('class');`

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis My logic was basically find the animate me portion within the recently clicked wrapper. I'm new to all this so any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question exactly but since I answered a similar question a bit ago i figured I would bring this to your attention:

There's a much easier way to do this in only 4 lines of code.

```
$("[data-toggle='slider']").click( function(e) {
    var next_of_kin = "[data-parent='" + e.target.id + "']";
    $(next_of_kin).toggleClass('close');
});
```

All you have to do is make the appropriate "close" class and assign a data-parent and data-toggle attributes where needed.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JA7qY/